# Is there such utility functions in Perl?

Tags: perl

1. Get current requested url (no parameters)
2. Get all GET parameters as hash
3. Convert hash to `key1=val1&key2=val2...`

I think these are necessary tools in web development.

How do you do this in Perl?

Comment: You type `perldoc CGI` at a terminal and read.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to re-invent web development again from scratch. Don't do this.

The CGI module is also probably not a good place to start if you're new to this. Look at one of the many modern frameworks that already exist to prevent you from having to ever care about parsing request parameters, construct GET URL's and the like.

I like [Mojolicious](http://www.mojolicious.org) but it's one of many.

Answer (score 7):

The [CGI](http://p3rl.org/CGI) module provides all of these functions.

Comment: I don't find it there,it seems there's only API to get all parameter names,so I still need to build the string manually?

Comment: I don't find the `sub` to get the query string representation of all parameters in the format like `key1=val1&key2=val2...`,I can only get an array of keys.

Comment: And I can't find the `sub` to return request uri with `sub` of CGI.pm,though I can get it with `%ENV`

Comment: Did you see the `url()` method, and it's various options?